# CSS locating sibling by text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select the sibling Edit menu based on the text "Edit" something like this

css=ul.jd_menu li:contains("Edit") but it still select the File link, so in essence trying to find the list items by their text

here is the a smipppet of the source

```
<ul class="jd_menu" style="background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216);">
    <li class="" style="background-color: transparent;">
        File
        <ul class="jdm_events" style="left: 0px; top: 36px; display: none; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216);">
    </li>
    <li class="">
        Edit
```

Comment: please post your code a little more cleaner.

Comment: When you paste your code/markup, highlight it and use the Code Sample { } formatting button so that HTML does not get stripped out.  Otherwise your post is very hard to make sense of.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
<ul class="jdm_events" style="left: 0px; top: 36px; display: none; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216);">
```

is not actually closed, so the Edit <li> is under it instead of the parent <ul>.

Nevertheless, a :content() selector was considered for CSS3 but was rejected: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors

so there's no current way to do it in pure CSS. You could instead

1. Write Javascript to iterate through the elements' textContent to find the Edit, or
2. Put the required string as a custom attibute e.g. <li label="Edit">Edit...</li> then select that.